# Prometheus/Grafana SLO issue

Tags: prometheus, grafana, rate

I currently view my http_server_seconds_bucket response times in prometheus/grafana with the following query:

job:http_server_requests_seconds_bucket:rate5m{percentile="100", app="myapp"}

This works fine and returns the required result.

Looking at the results I can see that my app has the following results from this

Min - 6ms   Max - 1.435s Avg 32ms

I wanted to go further and show the percentage of responses that are 100ms and faster within 5m.  I tried a few variations but i don't seem to be to achieve this

Percentage of requests that are 100ms or quicker within 5mins

histogram_quantile(0.1,
sum by(app, le) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{app="myapp"}[5m]))) *100 /
sum by(app) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{app="myapp"}[5m])) *100

The above does render but shows wacky results up to 1638 %

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_bucket{le="0.1",app="myapp"}[5m]))
/
sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="myapp"}[5m]))
```

This should work if you have a duration bucket for 0.1 (100ms).